# "Drink from the bottle" vs. "Drink out of the bottle"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Can you please tell me if there is any difference between *drink from the bottle* and *drink out of the bottle*? For example:

> I didn't drink **from** that bottle.
>
> I didn't drink **out of** that bottle.

If there is no difference between them, I'd like to know if both are perfectly natural (I haven't been able to find an answer to the question on the internet).

Comment: Please tell us what how dictionaries define ["from"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from) and ["out of"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of). What did you understand?

Comment: I think _from_ could imply drinking some of the contents poured out into a glass, but _drinking out of_ a bottle means putting it directly to your lips.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "In that context, I can't see the difference, which why I asked the question. If the answer is obvious to you, then I would appreciate if you shared it with me. I've run the two sentences by Chat GTP and it told me the opposite of what Kate Bunting told me.

Comment: That's an important piece of research worthy of sharing. You should share with the community the research, just saying "the Internet" is pretty feeble and lazy. Do I know the answer? I think there's basically no difference. Why do *you* think there must be?